# Magento2: Reindex command issue

Tags: magento2, reindex

Reindex status is processing

[image]

Also index:reset command is not working

Got the error message below

[image]

Comment: Check indexer_state table what's the status of indexer over there

Comment: Indexer status is processing. @KamalPaliwal

Comment: Try changing it to invalid and then check if you are able to reindex.

Comment: I think you renamed the cli indexer:reset to sampledata:reset, try sampledata:reset

Comment: indexer:reindex command is working fine. But reset command is not working.

Comment: how to run sampledata:reset command @Hit's

Comment: You were having two issues that indexers keep on processing. Is it resolved by this. As @Hit's said, have you changed renamed reset command. You can try php bin/magento sampledata:reset

Comment: All customer list is not showing in admin panel and product also not showing in category page frontend @Hit's

Comment: Earlier those indexers were stuck I think as you have changed it in db then they won't be in processing state now and you can perform reindex now. For reset command try the comment above.

Comment: @MasudShaikh It means you have installed sample data in your setup try to reinstall it by php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

Comment: When I run reset command then my data will remove from the database or not? Because my data is more important. Customer list and category products @Hit's

Comment: Hi @KamalPaliwal, I have updated query from the database indexer_state table. The issue is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: My Magento v2.0.17 so reset command is not avilable for it. So we need to manualy updated from database.